# Does the drip edge need to be nailed into the OSB sheathing or framing also

Tags: roof, waterproofing, roofing

From everything I am reading online I am seeing the drip edge should be nailed with 1.5” nails but I can not find clarification if I need to try and hit the rafters each time which are 16inches on centers. OR should I only be expected to nail into the .5” osb sheathing used for the roof similar to the shingles? For the shingles I purchased 1.25” nails so I was thinking of using those instead since I have a big box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drip edge, like trim, can be fastened to sheathing. It's not necessary to fasten it to structure.

If sheathing is 0.5in, maximum nail size is 1.5in so that you penetrate not more than 1in to clear wiring and piping.